# No tests found when running instrumented tests with AndroidX

Tags: android, android-testing, androidx

I'm trying to run the standard ExampleInstrumentedTest in my Android project (which uses AndroidX), but get "No tests found" error instead. I've looked through the other questions and the documentation and I'm pretty sure I've done everything right, but maybe I'm overlooking anything?

Here is my app's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    // Gradle automatically adds 'android.test.runner' as a dependency.
    useLibrary 'android.test.runner'

    useLibrary 'android.test.base'
    useLibrary 'android.test.mock'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url("https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots")
    }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}


dependencies {
    // Core library
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0'

    // AndroidJUnitRunner and JUnit Rules
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'

    // Assertions
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
}

// More dependencies...
```

and ExampleInstrumentedTest.java:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider;
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    public void useAppContext() {
        Context appContext = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
        assertEquals("XXX", appContext.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

when I run the code, I get "No tests found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to replace my runner

```
"androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4"
```

with

```
"androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Comment: Yes, this answer is correct. Even if your test classes use @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class), from androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4, the instrumented tests will only be recognized if in build.gradle testInstrumentationRunner is set to "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner".

Answer (score 2):

I replaced -

`testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4"`

with -

`testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"`

Answer (score 1):

Look for app/src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml

change **android:name** to ***androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication***

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="Components Tests App"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
```

To

```
<application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:label="Components Tests App"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the "No tests found" issue fixed by following the instructions of Jim Andreas here: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-testing/issues/27

"If I click on the package and not the test, then AS does find the test and executes it. "

[image]

In that way, the test was run as "Android Instrumented Tests" rather than "Android JUnit". I think that is the root cause of the issue. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its a silly mistake, but for me I forgot to add

```
@Test
```

above my test function.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was caused by running Instrumented tests on an emulator with API 30 (Android 'R').
When I switch to another emulator with API 29 (Android 'Q') the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have this

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
}
```

and this in dependencies

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
```