# AndroidX Espresso Test: No tests were found and Empty test suite

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, androidx

I am trying to run **src/androidTest** which is Instrument test in my Android Project which uses **AndroidX** libraries, but I am getting `No tests were found` error and `Empty test suite` log.

I have checked all samples and documents which are using AndroidX libraries are doing same.

I have tried to setup `Edit Configurations` based on following link https://stackoverflow.com/a/53715513/1826656 But still no luck.

Am I doing anything wrong? or missing any steps?

Please check this image for [Test Run log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmafw.png)

`MainActivityTest.java` Code:

```
import static androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.typeText;
import static androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class MainActivityTest {

   @Rule
   ActivityTestRule mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class, false, false);

   @Test
   public void checkViewsVisibility() {
     // verify the visibility of recycler view on screen
     onView(withId(R.id.record_list_rv)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

     // verify the visibility of progressbar on screen
     onView(withId(R.id.progressBar)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

     // verify the visibility of no data TextView on screen By default it should be GONE
     onView(withId(R.id.no_data_tv)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

     onView(withId(R.id.no_data_tv)).check(matches(withText("No Data")));

     onView(withId(R.id.no_data_tv)).perform(typeText("No Data"));
   }
}
```

Gradle file dependencies:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunne"
    }

    testOptions {
        execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
    }
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Relevant related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53600222/no-tests-found-when-running-instrumented-tests-with-androidx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your defaultConfig. It should probably be:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Comment: Correcting a typo was also the solution in a case where I had created a custom `testInstrumentationRunner`, moved it to a new package, but forgot to update the value in the `build.gradle` file.  Unfortunately neither Android Studio nor `./gradlew :app:connectedAndroidTest` told me it could not find the runner, they just gave error messages that `No tests were found`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I also struggled to run UI tests. Checking (and trying) most of the things in similar topics gave no results for me. Finally I ran my instrumentation tests via gradle command:

`gradlew connectedProdDebugAndroidTest`

or (if you want to run single test, or tests in a single class)

`gradlew connectedProdDebugAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class={package.class}#{methodName}`

After running tests by command, somehow, it became possible to run them by dedicated button.

Answer (score -1):

For me after ensuring that all dependencies were available, changing the targetSdk from 30 to lower version solved my problem.